# Android - NullPointerException from creating an adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating an array adapter for a list view,
everything works ok, I have 2 fragments, and 2 buttons at the top of the action bar that changes between this 2 fragments.
my problem is that I get crashes if I move too fast between those frags, when I open fragOne, switch to fragTwo, and then quickly move back to fragOne.. fragOne throws a NPE from the getActivity context..

that's the line that crashes:

```
adapter = new MainFragmentDocumentAdapter(getActivity(), docsList, DocumentsFragment.this, page);
```

the log report :

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bbb.app, PID: 17438
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:104)
        at com.bbb.app.UI.adapters.MainFragmentDocumentAdapter.<init>(MainFragmentDocumentAdapter.java:51)
```

any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: You get crashes because of the fragment lifecycle issues that sometimes causes getActivity() to be null.

Comment: getApplicationContext() is not optimal because it will not style anything within the adapter. Either ContextThemeWrapper the application Context with the app theme or make the adapter a global object so that when the fragment resumes it wont try to instantiate another adapter and your app wont crash.

Comment: jvrodrigues thanks for your answer, could you explain a bit more about it? I didn't understand it completely, thanks!

Comment: *change getActivity() with getApplicationContext()* i love [programming by permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation) ...  problem is prolly in premature `getActivity()` call ... seems like you are calling it from "constructor" (fx in constructor or as a field initializer) ... similar questions were asked many times

Comment: in which method did you put the creation of the adapter ? if the fragments are in tabs, why do they need to be recreated each time you switch tabs ?

Comment: the creation of the adapter is in a method that retrieve documents from a server. and what do you mean Lena? how can I replace a fragment on the screen without recreating it?

Comment: @LozeRi http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle ... `Fragment.getActivity()` returns `null` untill `onAttach` is called ... so you have to move creation of adapter after this point in fragment's lifecycle ....

Answer (score 44, accepted):

So basically after lots of check I found out that the problem was that I was returning to that fragment while inside a different fragment because I had a listener pointing out there and trying to open that method.

basically I just wrapped it in a

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
    // Code goes here.
}
```

and problem solved.

thanks a lot though for all the help guys !

Comment: Where do you put this? I can't wrap the return statement with this.

Comment: I was having a similar problem that I spent 2 days trying to solve. Thanks for taking the time to post the solution to your question.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and scratching my head after seeing this answer.  What I have found out from this mornings research is, at any time if your getActivity() or getContext() is null that means your have a serious bug in your code.  In my case, I was trying load the fragment code without attaching it to the Activity which was done based on a flag.  That said, I ensured the code is getting loaded only if the flag is true and the fragment is attached to the activity.  now the good news:  PROBLEM SOLVED!  Happy coding... :)

Answer (score 2):

if you are on a Fragment check if the fragment is added.

```
{
    ... 

    if (!this.isAdded()) { //this = current fragment
        return;
    }
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this.

inside activity

```
public static UsageRecommendationTabActivity getInstance() {
        return activityInstance;
    }
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
activityInstance=this;
}
```

inside fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof UsageRecommendationTabActivity)
            mParentActivity = (UsageRecommendationTabActivity) activity;
        if (mParentActivity == null)
            mParentActivity = UsageRecommendationTabActivity.getInstance();
    }
```

and then call your adapter

```
adapter = new MainFragmentDocumentAdapter(mParentActivity, docsList, DocumentsFragment.this, page);
```

Comment: interesting idea! will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

**Add checking for getContext()!=null**

Before block

```
mAdapter = new SimpleHomeItemAdapter(getActivity(), mList);
listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

For example:

```
if (getActivity()!=null){

mAdapter = new SimpleHomeItemAdapter(getActivity(), mList);
listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use try catch block,
it worked for me