# I'm trying to fill a ListView with place holder data using a BaseAdapter and put it inside a fragment but the app crashes on start up for some reason

Tags: java, android

Thank you for your time.

MainActivity

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    FragmentB fragB = new FragmentB();
    FragmentManager fragManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.add(R.id.cmll,fragB,"fragB");
    fragTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My Fragment

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    private Context myContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        myContext=context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        MyBaseAdapter adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(myContext);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

My BaseAdapter Class

i know it doesn't use the View Holder design pattern yet but i thought it should still display without crashing.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context myContext;
    private ArrayList<ListViewInfo> list;

    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context) {
        myContext = context;
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] test_10char = {"AaaAaaAaaA","BbbBbbBbbB","CccCccCccC"};
        String[] test_3char = {"Aaa","Bbb","Ccc"};
        int[] ints = {R.drawable.test_sunny,R.drawable.test_sunny,R.drawable.test_sunny};

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            list.add(new ListViewInfo(test_10char[i], test_3char[i], ints[i]));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View singleRowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout,parent,false);

        TextView date = (TextView) singleRowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView temp = (TextView) singleRowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) singleRowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        ListViewInfo tempLVI = list.get(position);

        date.setText(tempLVI.getDate());
        temp.setText(tempLVI.getTemp());
        icon.setImageResource(tempLVI.getImageID());

        return singleRowView;
    }
}
```

Error Log

```
03-22 21:42:08.421 4130-4130/com.eli.myweatherapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.eli.myweatherapp, PID: 4130
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.eli.myweatherapp.MyBaseAdapter.getView(MyBaseAdapter.java:52)
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2387)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:731)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5464)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17485)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lan
```

I have a ListViewInfo class too but its just three variables and get methods.

Thank you in advance for your help. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Can you include the logs?

Comment: I'm new to android and programing generally. is this what your looking for:

Comment: 03-22 21:42:08.421 4130-4130/com.askowitz.eli.myweatherapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.askowitz.eli.myweatherapp, PID: 4130
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.askowitz.eli.myweatherapp.MyBaseAdapter.getView(MyBaseAdapter.java:52)

Comment: Yes. Is that the complete logs? Normally it's more than a few lines..

Comment: i edited the post to include everything that relevant i think. if I am missing something a can definitly add it

Comment: Have you seen this similar [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414480/android-nullpointerexception-from-creating-an-adapter)? Try out the selected answer and let me know if it works.. Also, add some logs in the `if statement` so you'd know if the `getActivity()` is null or not. ;)

Comment: it still crashed. i just tried putting the instantiation of ListView in the if statement from the other post you recommended like this:

Comment: if (getActivity() != null) {
            Log.e("test","getActivity not null");
            ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
            MyBaseAdapter adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(myContext);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewGroup parent` arguments of `getView` has context info like this: `Context context = parent.getContext();`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

to

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: thanks you so much. that worked. i really appreciate it.